# How to pass the dynamic created props to the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the react js. Here , I have a table which has checkbox functionality.In this I am creating a dynamic state and I want to pass that to the child component where the actual table is

My code is like ,

**JobList.js**

```
    class JobList extends React.Component { 

    constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
          isCheckd: false
     }

     handleCheckBox = () => {
        this.setState({
          isCheckd: !this.state.isCheckd
        }, () => {
          this.props.jobs.forEach((item) => this.setState({ [item.jdName]: this.state.isCheckd }))
        });
      }

      handleTableCheckboxChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: e.target.checked
        }, () => {
          const uncheckedItems = this.props.jobs.filter((item) => !this.state[item.jdName])
          this.setState({
            isCheckd: uncheckedItems.length === 0 ? true : false
          });
        });
      }
     return() (
       <table className="table" id="actions-table">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td className="text-right mr-1"><input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.isCheckd} onChange={this.handleCheckBox} />
    </td> </tr></tbody></table>
    }
 <UserJobsTabel
              jobList={filteredList}
              sortAscending={this.sortData}
              sortCountAndScoreAscending={this.sortNumbersAscending}
              addNewRow={this.addNewRow}
              isRowAddingEditorVisible={this.props.isRowAddingEditorVisible}
              removeRow={this.removeRow}
              checked={this.state.isCheckd}
              handleTableCheckboxChange={this.handleTableCheckboxChange} />
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    jobs: state.UserJobs.jobList,
}
}
```

Now, In this code I am trying to check and uncheck the checkboxes.

```
this.state[item.jdName] so this state is getting generated for the each element in the array.
```

Now, I want to pass it to the `UserJobsTable` .

```
   const UserJobsTable = (props) => {
     return (
    <tbody className="text-center">
              {props.isRowAddingEditorVisible && <RowAddingEditor removeRow={props.removeRow} />}
              {props.jobList && props.jobList && props.jobList.length > 0 && props.jobList.map((item, key) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={key}>
                    <td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" name={props.key} checked={props[item.jdName]}   onChange={props.handleTableCheckboxChange} /></td></tr></tbody> ) }




 handleTableCheckboxChange = (e) => {
      this.props.jobs.filter((item) => this.setState(prevState => ({
        dynamicProp: {
          ...prevState.dynamicProp,
          [item.jdName]: e.target.name === [item.jdName] ? true : false
        }
      })
      ))
  }
```

I want to set it to the `checkbox` . So, I am not getting a way through which I can pass this state. is there any way I can do this ?

Comment: is your render() function is working properly without return() and also without parent closing element

Comment: No, I forgot to add that

Comment: please keep clear code so we can determine issue

Comment: Sure Sorry this mistake

Comment: now also its wrong ,where is the render()

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the dynamic property under a key and pass it.

```
this.state = {
  isCheckd: false,
  dynamicProp: {}
}

handleCheckBox = () => {
  this.setState({
    isCheckd: !this.state.isCheckd
  }, () => {
    this.props.jobs.forEach((item) => 
      this.setState(prevState => { 
        dynamicProp: {
          ...prevState.dynamicProp,
          [item.jdName]: prevState.isCheckd
        }
      })
    )
  });
}
```

In all your setState, you do

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  dynamicProp: {
    ...prevState.dynamicProp,
    [item.jdName]: prevState.isCheckd
  }
})
```

and to pass it to the child accordingly.

Comment: I want to pass it to the child component.

Comment: what about the setState ?

Comment: Hi do I need to change anything in the method handleTableCheckboxChange ?

Comment: Yes, you have to change all the methods where you are calling `setState`

Comment: It has that const uncheckedItems = this.props.jobs.filter((item) => !this.state[item.jdName])

Comment: could u please check with the second method I am getting confused

Comment: this is getting only one key value pair , it should have all that present in that array

Comment: is there any thing that I can do ? Because I am  getting the syntax errors now. for that spread operator.

Comment: handleCheckBox = () => {
    this.setState({
      isCheckd: !this.state.isCheckd
    }, () => {
      this.props.jobs.forEach((item) =>
        this.setState(prevState => {
          dynamicProp: {
          ...prevState.dynamicProp,
          [item.jdName]: prevState.isCheckd
        }
      })
    )
});
}  used this.  for spread operator it is saying declaration or statement is expected

Comment: I have added your updated code but still it gives me the same error

Comment: So, the parenthesis were missing in this. so because of that it was giving me that error. Now, It has all the objects

Comment: So, In this now If I check for one then all are getting checked

Comment: I have updated the code what I tried for the second method could you please check that